# How to fixed header of the table to the top of the page if table must be scrolable vertically?

Tags: header, fixed, vertical-scrolling

I have table which is very long vertically, then it must use `overflow: auto hidden`.
I have to prepare header of this table as fixed to the top of the page after scroll (prevent to hide header of the table after scrolling).

The problem is when I trying to use `position: fixed; top: 100px` on the thead or thead tr, this header is losing conection to the table and tbody and width of this is not as tbody (th aren't connected to appropriate td in body).
Also tbody is losing overflow: auto hidden and now has typical width 100% of the page.

```
SOME CONTENT BEFORE
<div style="overflow: auto;" class="table-responsive">
  <table class="products-table">
     <thead>
        <tr>
           <th>First</th>
           <th>Second</th>
           <th>Third</th>
           <th>Fourth</th>
           <th>Fifth</th>
           <th>Sixth</th>
           <th>...</th>
           <th>...</th>
           <th>...</th>
           <th>...</th>
         </tr>
      </thead>

      <tbody>
        <tr>
           <td>First</td>
           <td>Second</td>
           <td>Third</td>
           <td>Fourth</td>
           <td>Fifth</td>
           <td>Sixth</td>
           <td>...</td>
           <td>...</td>
           <td>...</td>
           <td>...</td>
         </tr>                            
      </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
SOME CONTENT AFTER
```

Styling:

```
.products-table
  border-collapse: separate
  border-spacing: 0 12px
  min-width: 100%
  font-size: 15px
  border-bottom: 4px solid grey

  td,th
    padding: 0 10px
    max-width: 300px
    &:first-of-type
      border-radius: 9px 0 0 9px
      padding-left: 14px
    &:last-of-type
      border-radius: 0 9px 9px 0
      padding-right: 14px
  thead
    background-color: grey
    color: white
    font-weight: 700
    th
      height: 26px
      white-space: nowrap
      a
        color: white
  tbody
    tr
      padding: 0 14px
      td
        word-break: break-word
        background-color: white
        max-width: 300px
      &:nth-of-type(odd) td
        background-color: #f6f6f6
```

Help, please...

I have tried yet many options based on similar questions, like for example position sticky.

Answer (score 0):

You may add the following codes into ur css.

```
thead tr th {
  /*Fixed Scroll*/
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 9999;
}

table {
  position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly it don't work. I need make thead fixed to the page to see this all the time when I scrolling page. Table is not scrollable horizontally. Only vertically.